# Sending an email in Kentico 13 - Liquid issue?

Tags: e-commerce, liquid, kentico

Under Ecommerce -> orders -> order -> shipping, I want to be able to send customers an email from Kentico when I change order status to (what I created -- shipped).

Email fires. Text works. I THINK I have the right variable in there, but it seems to be only recognizing it as text. Anyone have an idea?

{% if (Order.OrderStatus.StatusName == "Shipped") {"           Order Update    Your Order          Your shipment is on its way! Here's your tracking number: {{ Order.CustomData.m_c_orderShippingForm_OrderTrackingNumber_txtText }}

"} |(encode)false #%}

Comment: Your shipment is on its way! Here's your tracking number: {{ Order.CustomData.m_c_orderShippingForm_OrderTrackingNumber_txtText }}

When I change the order status from anything to "Shipped". This is all the email displays. No actual tracking.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may have your macro wrong.  This value:

`m_c_orderShippingForm_OrderTrackingNumber_txtText`

is the html ID of that generated at runtime for that field. What you actually need is the field/column name.  So if your column name is `OrderTrackingNumber`, then you'd use this:

`Order.CustomData.OrderTrackingNumber`

Comment: If the macro still didn't resolve I would try this in addition:
{ "Order Update Your Order Your shipment is on its way! Here's your tracking number: " + {{ Order.CustomData.OrderTrackingNumber }} }